# IdFtp and SSL : How to connect securely?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm on Delphi 10.3.3 and i'm trying to use TIdFTP to upload files to my own site. To avoid people stealing my username / password, i want to do it using SSL, as in the past i used without SSL and ended up having problems.

So i'm using TIdFTP and TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL, with the correct DLLs on the app folder.

Problem is, everytime i call TIdFTP.connect, i always get an error, except if i don't use SSL.

Here are the messages i get with different combinations of UseTLS property :

```
utNoTLSSupport - Works but exposes by traffic 
utUseExplicitTLS - Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer.
utUseImplicitTLS - Socket Error # 10061 Connection refused.
utUseRequireTLS - Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer.
```

Please help !

Thanks

Comment: Does your FTP server even support SSL/TLS to begin with? If so, are you sure you are connecting to the correct `Port`? Changing the `UseTLS` property may change the `Port` property. It is really hard to diagnose your issue without knowing your setup.

Comment: I could make it work with this combination : UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS and SSLOptions.method=sslvSSLv23 . Is this correct ?

Comment: what was your setup like before that didn't work? You really shouldn't be setting `SSLOptions.Method` manually, use `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` instead. Setting `Method=sslvSSLv23` will just set `SSLVersions=[sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]`. The default is `SSLVersions=[sslvTLSv1]`. So maybe the server just doesn't support TLS 1.0 and the fix was enabling TLS 1.1 or 1.2